# How to download a file stored on Google Drive from an Android app?

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I am writing a android app that needs to download a file from the web upon app launch.

This is the method that is used to download the file.

`private InputStream downloadUrl(String urlString) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.connect();
        return conn.getInputStream();
    }`

I have tried the following without much success.

- Share the file on Google drive (Public on the web), and use the given "share URL" to download - Gives an error - Connection refused
- Publish the file on web (via Google Drive) and use the given "publish URL" to download - Got this error - Unable to resolve host docs.google.com

Is there a possibility to use Google drive for this purpose?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You'd like to use [DriveApi.getFile](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/DriveApi.html) and [DriveFile.openContents](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/DriveFile.html) to retrieve the file in Google Drive. As far as I know, you cannot download the file directly via url.

I'm using the code like this:

```
    DriveFile file = Drive.DriveApi.getFile(client, driveId);
    DriveApi.ContentsResult contentsResult = file.openContents(client, DriveFile.MODE_READ_ONLY, null).await();
    if (!contentsResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
        error = new Error("failed in retrieving the file content for " + driveId);
        return null;
    }

    return getInputStream();
```